dmesg + many messages as error count since last fsck
we have kafka cluster with 3 VM machines. , when each kafka machines use the sdb disk ( VMDK disk ) in order to store the data
on all machines we seen the following kernel messages
[1123783.849575] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
[1123783.849582] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1595958527: ext4_writepages:2414
[1123783.849586] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1613639279: ext4_put_super:791
[1210205.709917] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
[1210205.709937] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1595958527: ext4_writepages:2414
[1210205.709944] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1613639279: ext4_put_super:791
[1296627.570121] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
[1296627.570141] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1595958527: ext4_writepages:2414
[1296627.570147] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1613639279: ext4_put_super:791
[1383049.419003] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
[1383049.419019] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1595958527: ext4_writepages:2414
[1383049.419025] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1613639279: ext4_put_super:791
[1469471.269771] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
.
.
.

red hat explain this messages as the following.  ( from case - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/383993 )
Issue
I see the following lines in /var/log/messages:
kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd1): error count: 5
kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd1): initial error at 1369732760: ext4_lookup:1044: inode 11534366
kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd1): last error at 1369733705: ext4_lookup:1044: inode 11534366

Resolution
These are not errors, they're informational messages; however, they may be referencing other possible historical errors.
These error counts should be reset once a successfully fsck has been run; however prior to e2fsprogs-1.41.12-18 a bug was preventing the reset. This has been corrected in e2fsprogs-1.41.12-18 via errata.
the messages that we get on our Kafka cluster are little diff from the redhat case
so we are more worry about the sdb disks ,
from what red hat say they not so worry because they are explained the messages as they're informational messages
so about my kernel messages, I can umount the disk from mount-point and do fsck in order to fix the Erros ,
but my question is how much I need to be worry about the following messages:
[1123783.849575] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
[1123783.849582] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1595958527: ext4_writepages:2414
[1123783.849586] EXT4-fs (sdb): last error at time 1613639279: ext4_put_super:791
[1210205.709917] EXT4-fs (sdb): error count since last fsck: 9
[1210205.709937] EXT4-fs (sdb): initial error at time 1595958527: ext4_writepages:2414


It seems fairly obvious that this is exactly what the RedHat document is talking about; the "initial error" and "last error" lines are simply reporting the historical errors. Make sure that your e2fsprogs version is more recent that the one in the RedHat document, then fsck, and the errors should go away. Since the dates represent dates in 2020 and 2021:
[~]$ date -d @1595958527
Tue Jul 28 13:48:47 EDT 2020
[~]$ date -d @1613639279
Thu Feb 18 04:07:59 EST 2021

you can safely ignore them, I think.
